# HTML tabindex dynamic

Tags: html, angular, tabindex

I have some pages with a structure like the below:

Page 1:

Component A:
question 1
question 2

Component B:
question 3
question 4

Component C:
question 5
question 6

Page 2:

Component A:
question 1
question 2

Component B: (use flex-direction: column-reverse; to revert order question)
question 4
question 3

Component C: (use flex-direction: column-reverse; to revert order question)
question 6
question 5

How to tabindex work same behavior in 2 pages(top to down and left to right)?

simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ra1jtd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: can you set a stackblitz demo?

Comment: there is nothing in your stackblitz link. It's completely a new project. Set an example with your components.

Comment: @debugger please recheck, I have created 2 button with CSS,
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button>Left</button>
  <button>Right</button>
</div>
.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

Comment: So what do you basically want? What you have to do with the buttons?

Comment: Button, link, input, dropdown...., In the example, when you tab it will focus to left button first and then the second tab, it will focus to the right button(I expect right first), because I reorder button by CSS. And the component reuse on some pages, and the difference between just use CSS to reorder elements in components. I want tabindex behavior correct on the page  with CSS reorder element of component

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tabindex attribute on the question components

Component HTML

```
<div [class.reversed]="isRevesed">
 <input type="text" placeholder="question 1" [tabindex]="getTapIndex(0)">
 <input type="text" placeholder="question 2" [tabindex]="getTapIndex(1)">
<div>
```

Component TS

```
@Input() isRevesed:boolean = false;
indexes:number[]=[1,2]
public getTapIndex(index:number):number {
  return (this.isRevesed) ? this.indexes[this.indexes.length - (index + 1)] : this.indexes[index];
}
```

of course can be made a lot cleaner, if we knew a bit more about your concreate implementation. But i hope the idea makes sense